# How can I get the dimensions of an img loaded with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading an image using jquery:

```
var myImg = new Image();

$(myImg).load(function(){
    console.log("image dimensions:"); // what should I put here ?
}).attr("src", "/path/toImg/");
```

When the img is loaded, is there a way to get it's width and height ?
Notice that the problem is that I want to have this info BEFORE the img is appended to the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should just be:

```
$(myImg).load(function(){
    var w = this.width;
    var h = this.height;
    ...
}).attr("src", "/path/toImg/");
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/c4JJf/

Comment: Yep, simplest answers are often the best ;-) Somehow, I was confused when trying to do $(this).width() and $(this).height()

Comment: @RunningTurtle yup, the jQuery methods look at the dimensions of elements already visible on the page.  But `img` elements also have direct `.width` and `.height` _properties_ which can be changed, but which default to the actual size.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var curHeight;
var curWidth;

function getImgSize(imgSrc)
{
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = imgSrc;
    curHeight = newImg.height;
    curWidth = newImg.width;    
}
```

Comment: The image will likely not be loaded yet at the point you're trying to access its dimensions.